# edmx file corrupt after adding stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Working on an existing ASP MVC 3 application.  The app has an edmx file with around 30 tables (entities) and 4 or 5 views.  I created a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, and after adding the stored procedure to the existing edmx file, the edmx file becomes corrupt.

By corrupt I mean, one of the views has all it's columns duplicated, so it now looks like:

PersonId
FirstName
LastName
personid
firstname
lastname

which causes several 'is not mapped' errors to occur.

Also, the application acts as if about half the models do not exist.  For example, there is an existing view model that references 12 different models, and I get the "namespace or type does not exist, are you missing a reference?" and so forth.

I have tried to restore the edmx file from an old version, and have even rebuilt.  restoring from old did not help, but rebuilding worked, until I added the stred proc again.

Could there be something wrong with my stored proc? Other ideas?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue once, so what i did was i deleted the view and then updated the edmx (right click on the canvas and update ) by adding the view again

Comment: I tried that but didn't work.  I found an earlier copy of the edmx file and restored that, I was able to rebuild, but as soon as  I add the stored proc, it corrupts again.